# When is「泣かない」used to mean 「泣かないで」?

Tags: grammar, て-form, imperatives

『あなたの番です』第１２話 has a scene where 黒島沙和, female in her early 20s, comforts 榎本総一, a 14 year old boy.

> 黒島「猫．．．それ．．．」
> 榎本「動かないんです。病院、知りませんか？」
> 黒島「でも．．．もう死んじゃってるんじゃないかな．．．」
> 榎本は泣いてしまう。
> 黒島「泣かない！泣かない！」

It is interesting that it isn't「泣かないで」which is what I would expect her say. How can a declarative sentence be used in place of a request/command?

I know young boys are often called 「僕」because the speaker assume their POV when talking to them. Is that the reason why 黒島 says 「泣かない」instead of「泣かないで」here? But the teenage boy is 14, way past the phase when he is addressed as 「僕」.

Comment: I really don't think this should be closed as this construction - two repeating negative verbs 〜ない〜ない - is a rather unique and common case in my experience.